# Why isn't my histogram showing the number 9?

Tags: r

I have a variable named `labels` with the following values:

```
   [1] 1 0 1 4 0 0 7 3 5 3 8 9 1 3 3 1 2 0 7 5 8 6 2 0 2 3 6 9 9 7 8 9 4 9 2 1 3
  [38] 1 1 4 9 1 4 4 2 6 3 7 7 4 7 5 1 9 0 2 2 3 9 1 1 1 5 0 6 3 4 8 1 0 3 9 6 2
  [75] 6 4 7 1 4 1 5 4 8 9 2 9 9 8 9 6 3 6 4 6 2 9 1 2 0 5 9 2 7 7 2 8 8 5 0 6 0
 [112] 0 2 9 0 4 7 7 1 5 7 9 4 6 1 5 7 6 5 0 4 8 7 6 1 8 7 3 7 3 1 0 3 4 5 4 0 5
 [149] 4 0 3 5 1 0 8 3 7 0 9 6 6 9 5 4 6 9 3 5 4 2 4 8 7 7 5 8 8 8 2 6 9 3 1 0 4
 [186] 1 5 9 0 6 2 1 3 0 6 0 0 8 3 2 0 0 6 0 0 4 7 2 7 1 9 9 3 9 8 4 6 6 5 3 8 1
 [223] 8 7 1 3 7 6 3 6 3 6 3 2 3 2 2 7 9 2 3 2 7 5 5 8 8 2 0 1 4 0 6 3 7 1 1 1 4
 [260] 7 0 2 9 2 0 5 6 0 8 9 6 2 0 0 7 2 0 4 2 0 9 1 6 9 3 0 0 2 0 6 8 4 0 7 2 1
 [297] 9 5 2 4 8 5 2 9 7 9 2 9 7 4 9 3 2 7 3 6 3 6 8 8 3 7 0 9 2 7 9 0 5 4 5 8 4
 [334] 3 3 1 7 8 9 7 6 2 1 7 0 5 6 5 2 9 5 4 6 2 2 2 9 0 7 7 2 2 6 3 4 2 0 5 9 6
 [371] 2 1 9 0 6 0 4 8 4 3 1 5 4 2 9 5 7 3 1 5 4 5 3 7 3 8 6 2 4 6 1 1 4 0 0 5 8
 [408] 6 7 4 2 8 0 2 5 4 8 3 0 6 4 8 6 4 1 8 1 5 4 9 4 3 2 0 5 0 7 9 2 9 8 9 6 5
 [445] 2 4 4 6 4 8 4 1 7 5 8 9 5 9 3 2 5 8 2 2 7 2 8 4 1 9 3 6 0 2 2 9 1 2 7 2 1
 [482] 3 4 9 1 8 0 2 2 3 4 1 3 7 4 1 4 1 5 9 6 9 0 5 7 6 8 2 0 7 3 5 8 2 8 2 4 8
 [519] 5 8 9 7 1 2 4 5 5 1 8 1 4 4 6 5 8 9 2 3 0 5 1 4 0 5 1 2 9 2 4 1 6 8 0 4 9
 [556] 0 0 5 9 2 3 5 9 4 4 3 9 2 3 5 6 5 2 7 2 4 2 4 7 2 5 3 7 6 1 0 7 5 4 5 1 6
 [593] 9 7 1 6 3 3 1 2 2 0 5 0 6 8 3 6 7 7 3 8 1 7 9 3 9 2 8 3 7 4 1 2 3 6 5 0 1
 [630] 8 6 9 2 1 6 0 2 8 0 8 8 9 1 2 2 1 4 8 1 4 4 5 1 8 7 7 9 7 0 6 9 4 5 6 2 5
 [667] 7 4 7 2 3 0 8 4 8 0 0 9 7 7 9 8 2 1 6 5 5 1 1 9 7 7 8 6 4 7 5 3 1 6 4 5 7
 [704] 4 1 8 3 5 1 7 1 1 8 6 4 3 8 3 1 2 8 9 0 9 1 2 3 3 0 3 0 2 0 3 3 8 3 5 7 0
 [741] 5 9 0 5 9 1 5 1 1 2 6 5 5 4 5 1 6 0 2 2 8 0 7 1 0 8 5 6 3 2 9 4 3 6 0 3 4
 [778] 1 5 9 3 0 5 0 6 2 7 6 6 6 9 6 7 8 2 0 6 0 8 9 5 3 6 7 4 3 9 7 2 0 4 7 2 2
 [815] 8 2 7 0 4 0 5 2 8 7 7 9 1 4 0 1 1 2 3 6 2 0 6 6 1 9 4 5 2 7 7 8 9 5 8 3 8
 [852] 5 6 2 0 9 7 1 8 2 6 9 8 4 9 4 1 3 8 4 0 7 7 3 7 6 6 8 8 2 7 0 4 3 7 7 0 8
 [889] 4 7 4 0 6 9 8 6 0 1 6 4 5 2 7 3 6 2 2 9 2 7 4 8 7 2 9 5 3 4 8 0 4 4 6 5 6
 [926] 1 2 2 8 4 5 7 8 0 6 8 9 1 7 7 2 6 3 9 9 1 0 4 2 5 4 4 9 2 6 7 2 8 3 3 2 7
 [963] 0 4 7 0 7 7 8 1 7 3 7 8 0 1 0 2 9 7 6 2 2 6 9 0 6 8 8 9 6 3 5 0 2 2 5 9 6
[1000] 4
```

For some reason when I run `hist(labels)` it returns the following histogram which has no occurrences of the number 9.

[image]

What Am i missing here?

Comment: I am not a downvoter, however given you comments on @dirks answer suggest that your understanding and interpretation of what a histogram is appears to be your issue. This shows a lack of research effort (or perhaps that the question is not suited for SO).

Comment: @ Abe Miessler: Maybe you are just looking for `?barplot` rather than `?hist`. But it is difficult to guess, if we do not know what you intend to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `axis` to define the axis. (`plot.histogram` has some default values)

```
labels <- sample(1:9, 1000, replace = T)
.h <- hist(labels)
# if you save the histogram, then you can refer to the components
axis(1, at = .h$breaks))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The last bar counts the occurrences of 9.  You can check that by looking at the output of `hist()`.

```
R> x <- rep(1:9, each=10)
R> hh <- hist(x, breaks=0:9)       # also creates chart
R> str(hh)
List of 7
 $ breaks     : int [1:10] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 $ counts     : int [1:9] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
 $ intensities: num [1:9] 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 ...
 $ density    : num [1:9] 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 ...
 $ mids       : num [1:9] 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5
 $ xname      : chr "x"
 $ equidist   : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
R>
```

Nine counts of 10 as we expected.

Comment: Then what bar is counting the occurrences of zero?  Either way there are ten values and nine bars.  It seems like something is missing...

Comment: In your update you have 10 breaks and 9 counts.  Why is that?

Comment: Nine 'regions' defined by ten 'borders'. On the margin, if I set -Inf and Inf and 'borders' I get one region in-between, counting all values.  Now add one marker at zero...

Comment: So would I be correct to read my histogram as: `column1`: between 0 and 1 (aka 0 and 1) there are aprox. 200 elements, `Column2`: between 1.1 and 2 (aka 2) there are aprox 125 elements and so on?

Comment: Yes, see eg in the output the columns 'mids' giving the midpoints, and then giving the counts.  The is works with strict '<=' for the right border and '>' for the left, so '200 up to and including 1, 125 for greater 1 and up to 2' etc.